# OAuth2 and AdWords AdHoc Reports Authentication Issue

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-ads-api

Context: Windows 7, IE10, JScript, Google Adwords, OAuth2

I have generated an access_token and a refresh_token using the using the urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob technique and all appears to be okay. The tokens I've generated this way are working fine with Analytics calls. This issue is with Adwords calls to https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201309 . The header and data is as follows:

```
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=ya29.blahblah
developerToken: blahblah
clientCustomerId: blahblah
returnMoneyInMicros: false
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

__rdxml=<reportDefinition xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309"> <selector> <fields>CampaignId</fields> <fields>Id</fields> <fields>Impressions</fields> <fields>Clicks</fields> <fields>Cost</fields> <predicates> <field>Status</field> <operator>IN</operator> <values>ENABLED</values> <values>PAUSED</values> </predicates> </selector> <reportName>Custom Adgroup Performance Report</reportName> <reportType>ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType> <dateRangeType>LAST_7_DAYS</dateRangeType> <downloadFormat>CSV</downloadFormat> </reportDefinition>
```

The report XML is straight off the documentation.

When I submit that request I get the following error:

AuthenticationError.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_COOKIE_INVALID

**LATER**

I changed the header

```
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=ya29.blahblah
```

to

```
Authorization: Bearer ya29.blahblah
```

and am now getting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<reportDownloadError>
<ApiError>
<type>AuthenticationError.OAUTH_TOKEN_INVALID</type>
<trigger>&lt;null&gt;</trigger>
<fieldPath></fieldPath>
</ApiError>
</reportDownloadError>
```

The token, however, is current, having been regenerated just before the test.

**FINALLY**

Changed the scope to

```
https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/
```

and also referred to a non-MCC account.

**for Mikeys4u**

```
function OAuthConnect(client_id, scope, login_hint) {
  var url = XMAP("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?[1]&[2]&[3]&[4]&[5]&[6]",
      "response_type=code",
      "client_id=" + client_id,
      "redirect_uri=" + "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
      "scope=" + escape(scope),
      "state=acit",
      "login_hint=" + login_hint);

  var oIE = new ActiveXObject("InternetExplorer.Application");
  oIE.Visible = true;
  oIE.Navigate(url);
  while (oIE.busy) {
    WScript.Sleep(10);
  };
  var status = oIE.Document.title;
  while (status.indexOf("state=acit") === -1) {
    WScript.Sleep(100);
    status = oIE.Document.title;
  }
  // WScript.Echo(status);
  oIE.Quit();
  var code = RightOf(status, "&code=");
  return code;
}
```

That's referring to a lot of helper code (like XMAP and RightOf) but you should be able to get the drift.

The call of that code looks like

```
if (accessToken === "") {
  code = OAuthConnect(secrets.client_id, oCFG.retrieve(client + ".scope"), oCFG.retrieve(client + ".login_hint"));
```

This is JScript, by the way.

Comment: Amazing what a difference the correct scope makes.

Comment: Could you now post complete code as not sure what you mean by scope?

Comment: Thank you but I'm using PHP and trying adhoc way...cant seem to get anywhere. Need to find my ya.29xxxxxxx token, I am using a refresh token at the moment.....